# Python parsing integers inside parantheses in a string

Tags: python

I want to parse a simple string with python as -

`Limits paramA : (7, 45)  paramB : (0, 0) paramC : (1, 23)`

I want to extract 7, 45, 0, 0, 1, 23 in different integers.
Could someone tell me how can I extract this?

There are lot of string parsing questions in the forum, but I am not able to find the answer that suits me best.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the expected output for a string like `'Limits param1 : (7, 45) param2 : (0, 0)'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `regex`:

```
In [71]: import re

In [72]: strs="Limits paramA : (7, 45) paramB : (0, 0) paramC : (1, 23)"

In [74]: [int(digit) for digit in re.findall(r'\d+',strs)]
Out[74]: [7, 45, 0, 0, 1, 23]
```

Comment: Why use `{1,}` instead of `+`?

Comment: You beat me too it while I was typing something very similar (though I was using list comprehension to turn them into integers rather than map.)

Comment: Drop the brackets, `r'\d+'` is fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am kind of new to `regex`, @kwatford thanks.

Comment: @RajTendulkar `\d` is a digit(i.e 0-9), and `+` means `1` or more times. and then use `map()` to convert the strings into integers.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want all numbers in the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Limits paramA : (7, 45) paramB : (0, 0) paramC : (1, 23)'
>>> [int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+', s)]
[7, 45, 0, 0, 1, 23]
```

If you only want to find numbers within parentheses (same result in this case):

```
>>> [int(n) for m in re.findall(r'\(([\d, ]+)\)', s) for n in m.split(',')]
[7, 45, 0, 0, 1, 23]
```

Here is an example of where this difference might be important:

```
>>> s = 'Limits param1 : (7, 45) param2 : (0, 0) param3 : (1, 23)'
>>> [int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+', s)]
[1, 7, 45, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 23]
>>> [int(n) for m in re.findall(r'\(([\d, ]+)\)', s) for n in m.split(',')]
[7, 45, 0, 0, 1, 23]
```

Note that the first method also matches the `1` from `param1` and the `2` from `param2`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> import ast

>>> nums = [num for tup in [ast.literal_eval(tup) for tup in re.findall('\([^)]*\)', s)] for num in tup]
[7, 45, 0, 0, 1, 23]
```

Only extracts numbers inside parentheses.

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval()`, it's safer.